# Insert Stored Procedure, Using Asp.Net WebForm to Insert new [Customer]

Tags: asp.net, sql, stored-procedures

Can someone please help me create a stored procedure to insert a new customer from a web form.
I am having difficulty making the state a drop down list for customer to pick a state from the list and having that inserted into the database.

```
                    INSERT INTO Customer
                    (
                    Cust_First,
                    Cust_Middle,
                    Cust_Last,
                    Cust_Phone,
        Cust_Alt_Phone,
                    Cust_Email,
                    Add_Line1,
                    Add_Line2,
                    Add_Bill_Line1,
                    Add_Bill_Line2,
                    City,
                    State_Prov_Name,
                    Postal_Zip_Code,
                    Country_ID
                    )

                    VALUES
                    (
                    @Cust_First,
                    @Cust_Middle,
                    @Cust_Last,
                    @Cust_Phone,
        @Cust_Alt_Phone,
                    @Cust_Email,
                    @Add_Line1,
                    @Add_Line2,
                    @Add_Bill_Line1,
                    @Add_Bill_Line2,
                    @City,
                    @State_Prov_Name,
                    @Postal_Zip_Code,
                    @Country_ID
                    )">


        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Cust_First" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Cust_Middle" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Cust_Last" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Cust_Phone" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Cust_Alt_Phone" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Cust_Email" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Add_Line1" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Add_Line2" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Add_Bill_Line1" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Add_Bill_Line2" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
            <asp:Parameter Name="City" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Postal_Zip_Code" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Cust_ID" Type="Int32"></asp:Parameter>
            <asp:Parameter Name="State_Prov_Name" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Country_Name" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
        </InsertParameters>
```